# Django Admin list display cannot access foreign key attribute getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: django-admin

I'm trying to display a related field in the admin section but I'm getting the following error:

**'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ref_code'**

**models.py**

```
class Orden(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    producto = models.ManyToManyField(
        ProductosOrden)
    medio_de_venta = models.ForeignKey(MediosVenta, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    fecha_venta = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    ordenado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    promo = models.ForeignKey(Promos,null=True, blank=True, on_delete=CASCADE )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    vendido_por = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Ordenes"
        ordering = ["-id"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Cliente(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False)
    email_valido = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank= True, verbose_name='Email Válido')
    telefono = models.CharField(
        max_length=17, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Teléfono')
    lead = models.ForeignKey(Leads, models.SET_NULL,  null=True, blank=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    orden = models.ForeignKey(Orden, null=True, blank=True,  on_delete=CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Clientes"
        ordering = ["-id"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

**admin.py**

```
class ClienteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'nombre', 'activo', 'get_ref_code')
    readonly_fields=('id',)
    search_fields = ['nombre']
    actions = ['activa','desactivar']

    @admin.action(description='Desactivar')
    def desactivar(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(activo = False)

    @admin.action(description='Activar')
    def desactivar(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(activo = True)

    @admin.display(description= 'ref_code')
    def get_ref_code(self, obj):
        if not obj.orden.ref_code:
            return None
        else: 
            return obj.orden.ref_code
```

If I just use the return as:

```
return obj.orden
```

results are displayed with the *name*, but I want to display the *ref_code* results which is under the *Orden* model and it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct if condition because `orden` column is nullable in `Cliente` model.

```
@admin.display(description= 'ref_code')
    def get_ref_code(self, obj):
        if not obj.orden_id:
            return None
        else: 
            return obj.orden.ref_code
```